# IP Geolocation reliability

Tags: ip-address

Does anybody know how geolocation of IP addresses works? Are ISP obligated to show us real locations of IP addresses or not? How much are IP geolocation services that we can find on Internet reliable?

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about protocols above OSI layer-4 are explicitly off-topic here. There are no standards or requirements around geolocation. Geolocation is maintained by private companies, and each has its own sources for its database. Geolocation is often quite incorrect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the RIPE region (not sure for other Regional Internet Registry), ISP have to declare only the country in which an IP block is used, nothing more. (And I'm quite sure there's no check if this information is correct or not).

Geolocation services maintain their own database and gather information by various ways. For example many use the GPS feature of devices, becoming increasingly common in mobile devices, including laptops.

So if you open google maps, and allowed it to access the location service of your Operating System, google will now exactly where you are and can update its database with the location of your IP.

Some also use neighbor WiFi networks, maintaining a database of SSID / locations and cross those data with other sources.

How those services exactly works and how much reliable they are greatly vary by service, and this is not something we can answer on this SE site I think.